# NBA API: Looping a dictionary to get data frames

Tags: python, nba-api

I am trying to get a full database of all active players career stats in the NBA.

I'm relatively new to Python and am trying to figure out a way to iterate a loop function by looking up the playerID for each PlayerCareerStat data frame. Ultimately I will summarize and group the data so its easier to read but I am trying to return a list of all players career stats by season.

I am able to use the players.get_active_players() endpoint to return a list of all players with their player_id: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFxgv.png

With that, I am tryin to loop the Player_id through each data frame in the PlayerCareerStats() endpoint ... I think? Since the parameter for this endpoint requires a single player_id I can't seem to get all the players. Please see picture [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skM8Y.png

Does anyone know how I might be able to get the output I am trying to find?

Comment: don't post photos of your code. Post the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a function, it will end when it reaches `return`. So your function returns the player id, and doesn't move on to the part where you are trying to pull the career stats.

So get rid of that `return player['id']`, and the function should run all the way through:

```
from nba_api.stats.static import players
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import playercareerstats
import pandas as pd


def get_nba_id():
    nba_players = players.get_active_players()
    
    for player in nba_players:
        career_stats = playercareerstats.PlayerCareerStats(player_id=player['id'])
        career_df = career_stats.get_data_frames()[0]
        career_df['NAME'] = player['full_name']
        print(career_df)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work still

Comment: Ok. What doesn’t work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: And secondly, are you actually calling the function?

Comment: No it works, my apologies im still learning...I wasn't calling the function. I appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: @olideepo, cool. glad it worked. be sure to accept the solution if it met your needs